# Migrate models between different environments in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am writing a script that will be in charge of transferring data from production db to a new production db.

There is one Rails app connecting to each database. In the new app we have made some migrations that change the schema (remove columns, etc)

I tried to do this:

```
rails console old

2.0.0p247 :004 > tag = Tag.last.dup
=> #<Tag id: nil, description: " views", account_id: 46, screenshotBase64: "", user_id: 1, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
2.0.0p247 :005 > ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
2.0.0p247 :006 > tag.save
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'screenshotBase64' in 'field list
```

As we removed the `screenshotBase64` in the new db, it does not work.

Is there a way to do that with Rails ? Delete attributes from Rails model before save ?

Is there a better way to transfer all data from a user linked through its associations between two databases (changing ids in the new db) ?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you want to do here.  Is it just a one-off data copy?  If so then you can just copy the data and then run `rake db:migrate` for the new one: this will run the new migrations.

Is it not as simple as that?

Comment: Not really. We will have the two apps running in parallel for a while and we would like to be able to move an account with its dependencies from the old app to the new one and stick to the new schema at any time. A sort of data migration ?

Comment: When you say "in parallel", do you mean that the newer app will be used by real users?  Or is it just a staging app used for testing?  In other words, will there ever be data that is just on the new app, and not the live one, which you want to keep?

Comment: The idea was to give access to a beta version of the new app to real users. They will be able to 'migrate' aka copy their data from production app to beta app. At some point the beta will become the production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a try with this code

```
tag_attributes = Tag.last.attributes.dup
%w(id screenshotBase64).map{|method| tag_attributes.delete method}
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(:development)
tag = Tag.create(tag_attributes)
```

Comment: Thanks I am looking at this asap